# get error in connecting to magento store with android application

Tags: android, web-services, magento, xml-rpc

i want to connect  magento store installed on localhost via android app , i try

```
String sessionId = "";
            XMLRPCClient client = new XMLRPCClient("http://192.168.1.217/magento_test2/index.php/api/xmlprc");
            try {
                sessionId = (String)client.call("login", "test", "123456");
                Log.d("MY_XMLRPC_SUCCESS_SESSION_ID", sessionId);
                tv.setText("MY_XMLRPC_SUCCESS_SESSION_ID"+ sessionId);
            }
            catch (XMLRPCException e) {
                Log.d("MY_XMLRPCException_MSG", e.getMessage());
                tv.setText("MY_XMLRPCException_MSG"+ e.getMessage());
            }
```

but when i run application on my device i get this message : HTTP status code:404 !=200

can any body help me ? 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BAsed on the error message

```
HTTP status code:404 !=200
```

It sounds like your XML-RPC code tries to call the URL endpoint you provided

```
http://192.168.1.217/magento_test2/index.php/api/xmlprc
```

But received a HTTP status code of `404`.  That means page not found.  The network your phone is on can't access the URL

```
http://192.168.1.217/magento_test2/index.php/api/xmlprc
```

My guess would because `192.168.0.0` is an IP space reserved for private networks, and your android phone is either on the mobile carrier's network, or connected to a wifi network that can't access `192.168.1.217`.